# Choose values from array based on index of argmax from another array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given a dataframe with columns a1, b1 and a2, b2, I want to find the column index for the largest value out of a1, b1 and then get the value with the same relative column index out of a2, b2, as shown in the `want` column below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
df= pd.DataFrame({'a_1':[1,2,3], 'b_1': [2,1,3], 'a_2': [3,4,7], 'b_2':[5,6,8], 'want':[5, 4, 7]})
```

I was able to get this far, but I'm not sure what the best approach is for the final step:

```
# Get the argmax for a1, b1
df['c'] = df[['a_1', 'b_1']].idxmax(axis=1)

# Get the column index of the argmax
df['d'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: ['a_1', 'b_1'].index(x))
```

This is a simplified version of the problem - there are actually many more columns to search through - e.g. `a1-z1, a2-z2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two columns, this should do:

```
df['e'] = np.where(df['a_1']>=df['b_1'], df['a_2'], df['b_2'])
```

For several columns:

```
numcols = 2
idx_max = np.argmax(df.iloc[:, :numcols].values, 1)

df['e'] = df.iloc[:,numcols:2*numcols].values[np.arange(len(df)), idx_max]
```

You can also replace `df.iloc[...]` with the corresponding column names, e.g. `df.iloc[:, :numcols]` by `df[[a_1','b_1']]`

Comment: In the full example I'm working with, there are lots of columns, e.g. a1-z1 and a2-z2 - sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: Your edited np.argmax is similar to mine. I didn't see your edited when I composed my answer. I deleted mine :) +1

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
s=df[['a_1','b_1']].idxmax(1).replace(['a_1','b_1'],['a_2','b_2'])
df['value']=df.lookup(s.index,s)
df
Out[23]: 
   a_1  b_1  a_2  b_2  want  value
0    1    2    3    5     5      5
1    2    1    4    6     4      4
2    3    3    7    8     7      7
```

Comment: it is a nice combo of `replace` and `lookup` :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I initially came up with:

```
df['e'] = np.choose(df['d'].values, df[['a_2', 'b_2']].transpose().values)
```

I think this works, but is there a simpler way?

EDIT: It seems this only works as long as you have at most 32 columns to choose from, so other options are definitely better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) along with [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
cols = df.filter(regex=r'[a-zA-Z]+_1').idxmax(1).str.rstrip('1') + '2'
df['want'] = df.filter(regex=r'[a-zA-Z]+_2').lookup(df.index, cols)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   a_1  b_1  a_2  b_2  want
0    1    2    3    5     5
1    2    1    4    6     4
2    3    3    7    8     7
```